# GCP: Have rtmp and want to get back hls m3u8

Tags: google-cloud-platform, video-streaming

I want to have a stream over google cloud plattform, so that I have support for larger bandwich. I have a rtmp stream which I can send to gcp. I want to have back a hls m3u8 link from gcp. The in and out resolution should be 3840x1920 pixel. Is this possible with gcp? I did not find any usefull documentation to do this with gcp.

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: No, havent found anything helpful yet.

Answer (score 0):

Google Cloud Platform can be used in plenty of use cases, but to decided with one more suitable for you you should provide more information.

As a starting point, please have a look at the possible solution for [live streaming](https://gcp.solutions/diagram/media-live-streaming) and [transcoding](https://gcp.solutions/diagram/media-transcoding).

[image]

You can do even more with [Video AI](https://cloud.google.com/video-intelligence).

If you still have a some question, you can ask your question at [Google Groups](https://support.google.com/groups/answer/1067205?hl=en#:%7E:text=To%20join%20a%20group%2C%20click,on%20the%20left%2C%20click%20About.) or/and contact with [Google Sales](https://cloud.google.com/contac) or/and [Google Cloud Support](https://cloud.google.com/support-hub) for more assistance.